# Increase output width Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I'm using Jupyter Lab with Anaconda and I want to increase the output width so that the data doesn't wrap the line as shown in the image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5VPr.png)

I need to know how to increase the output width in Jupyter Lab with Anaconda3 and make it fixed for all new launcher.

Comment: Is that output from Pandas? It should be showing nicely rendered HTML display and not text and that will be on one line. Don't use `print()`, just put the code for what is making that on the last line **without** `print()`. (If you have to, wrap it in `display()` in place of `print()`.) You are using `print()` that is meant for terminals and I think it defaults to thinking there is a limit of 70 characters per line. I think. But you shouldn't use screenshots and if you do, also show what is triggering the output. Or better yet, also put in text what you are using.